# Get client certificate in java RMI (over SSL)

Tags: java, ssl, rmi

I have **a RMI service** running and clients connect to the skeleton over **SSL** to get information. I want to get **the client certificate** to extract t**he host name** and only allow the connection when specific (allowed) **hosts** try to connect to **the server**.

I tried overloading the `SslRMIServerSocketFactory` but I do not get **client certificates** there.
When I tried overloading the `SslRMIClientSocketFactory class`, I was able to get the server certificated on the client side, however I am unable to achieve the other way around.

Tried overriding the `createServerSocket()` method in `SslRMIServerSocketFactory` but I did not get any **client certificate** information.

Please find my attempt to get the client certificate in the code snippet mentioned below:

```
public class MyRMIServerSocket extends SslRMIServerSocketFactory implements RMIServerSocketFactory
```

{

```
private static SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;

@Override
public ServerSocket createServerSocket(int port) throws IOException
{
    if (sslSocketFactory == null)
    {
        sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    }
    return new ServerSocket(port)
    {
        public Socket accept() throws IOException
        {
            Socket socket = super.accept();
            SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory
                .createSocket(socket, socket.getInetAddress().getHostName(), socket.getPort(), true);
            sslSocket.setUseClientMode(false);
            sslSocket.setNeedClientAuth(true);
            sslSocket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new MyHandshakeListener());
            return sslSocket;
        }
    };
}
```

}

MyHandshakeListener returns me the client certificate.

```
public class MyHandshakeListener implements HandshakeCompletedListener
{
    @Override
    public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent event)
    {
        Principal clientPrinciple;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably tried *subclassing* (and overriding methods), not overloading. Either way, show what you tried and where exactly it didn't work.

Comment: @jorn updating the question with the implementation

Comment: You're on the right track, and it is ridiculous that Sun overlooked this and that it has stayed overlooked all these years. You don't need `implements RMIServerSocketFactory`. I would like to see the code where you install this. You should do so when constructing/exporting the remote object.

Comment: The above mentioned approach did not help! and I got null (certificate) in my handshake listener.

Comment: I am using it while creating the registry. 

RMIServerSocketFactory ssf = new MyServerSocketFactory();registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port, new SslRMIClientSocketFactory(), ssf); registry.bind("method", stub);

Comment: That's insufficient. You also need to use it for your own remote objects. Otherwise they are still insecure. You need to post the stack trace of the NPE, and your handshake completion listener.

Comment: @user207421this is the error I get
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

But I have the certificates added in both server and client

Comment: Also, update the handshake listener.

Comment: 1. You didn't post the stack trace. 2. You didn't post the code that causes the stack trace. 3. You are now talking about an `SSLHandshakeException` where previously you were talking about a `null`. Please make up your mind and clarify your question. It cannot be answered in its present form.

Comment: @user207421 apologies if I mentioned some other error. On looking the code again, I got null (peer certificate) when I set needClientAuth as false, which I think makes sense. On setting the value true I am facing this exception SSLHandshakeException. Could it be that my certificates are not correct? (not configured for two-way authentication)

Comment: From RFC 2246: "certificate_unknown
       Some other (unspecified) issue arose in processing the
       certificate, rendering it unacceptable." So the certificate got there but there was something wrong with it.